# Attempting to add a VNet to an Azure Website gives VPNNetworksetupfailure

Tags: azure, virtual-network

When attempting to put an existing Website (newly created) on to a Virtual Network (Created as part of the process) I get a vpnnetworksetupfailure message, but no other information. This is all done on new preview portal (portal.azure.com), as the old portal will not allow me to attach a VNet to a website.

Steps follow.

**Step one** is to create a Website instance, name etc doesn't matter, but for sake of simplicity I've left it all as it is (Standard S1 website, North Europe, On Existing Resource Group).

**Step two** Once the website is created, scroll to the *Networking* section on the Blade and select the *Virtual Network* action. On This select *Create new* and just give it a name *MyTestVpn*. I leave the DNS fields blank, and the *Address Space CIDR Block* as `10.0.0.0/24`. I get green ticks next to both of these fields, and so press *OK* to save changes, the VNet blade closes, and the Notifications button eventually (10 seconds or so) shows an error saying:

```
VpnNetworkSetupFailure
```

No other information, just that. Is there anyway to get the information as to why this isn't working? It certainly was working early december, in fact I'd say it was working up to the 19th of December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to do with the length of the name of the website instance.
So **name etc doesn't matter** as I wrote, was wrong. The name of the website I was using was something like: `Test-Site-Dev-North-Europe-uyvberui-212` which is *roughly* 54 characters (by chance).

When you create a new network from a website instance, the name for the *deployment* is `VPNNetworkSetupForWebsite-{WebsiteName}` which in this case would take the characters to `70`. In the events list (which is found by going to the Resource Group the website is in, then going to the *Monitoring* section) the message was finally found stating:

```
statusMessage:{"error":{"code":"InvalidDeployment","message":"The provided deployment name 'VPNNetworkSetupForWebsite-Test-Site-Dev-North-Europe-uyvberui-212' has a length of '70' which exceeds the maximum length of '64'."}}
```

So a website has a limit of 38 characters if you're intending to create the Virtual Network *from* the website blade (even though the Azure Portal gives you the green tick of success!)